# XDEBUG_SESSION not propagating page changes

Tags: php, netbeans, xdebug

I have been using Netbeans in Windows to successfully remotely debug my Linux web pages (php) for some time now.  I have recently been trying to set up a new Ubuntu Linux box and have installed on it the latest NetBeans (11), Apache2, PHP7.3 and the same php code I am getting some something odd happening.

Xdebug is definitely working.

I set "stop at first line and it stops there in "index.php".  That file immediately redirects (`header('location:Users/login.php')`) to "login.php". It again stops at the first line.  Furthermore I can set breakpoins in that file and they are obeyed - all looks good.
The form in "login.php" calls itself until the user has been verified when control is passed on to "Start.php".  Again it stops at the first line.
Start.php initially just puts up a menu and control in the next step is from a Javascript call back to itself with appropriate parameters set (depending on the menu choice). So the action will be something like:

```
$(location).prop('href', rooturl+'/Start.php?Database=".MUSICDB."');
```

After this redirection no further breakpoints are observed (including stop at first line).  This is exactly the same code as I used in previous setup which continues to work just fine. It seems to have lost any knowledge of the fact that it is in a debugging session.

Any clues what may be happening?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I found the problem......

The project was set up on the new m/c to start at localhost/index.php, but the variable "rooturl" was returning IPaddress/index.php.  Hence the system thought it had gone somewhere else, even though it actually went to the correct place.  On the old system I had set the project up to start at IPaddress/index.php.